# redirect call not working in servlets

Tags: jsp, redirect

when i try to redirect my `servlet` to error page `"error.jsp"` using `response.sendRedirect("/error.jsp")` it shows page not found error but when i change it to response.sendRedirect("error.jsp"), it works fine!

why is it so? why is relative path not working? `error.jsp` is saved in `WEB-CONTENT` folder.
The `dispatcher.foreward(request,response)`, works fine with relative url "/page01.jsp", even though both `page01.jsp` and `error.jsp` are in same directory `WEB-CONTENT`.
please explain.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a String starting with '/' to `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect` the path will be relative to the server and not your application. So, you should pass something like this to get this working:

`response.sendRedirect("/myapp/error.jsp");`

Answer (score 8):

First let's clear some vocabulary:

- `error.jsp` and `./../error.jsp` are examples of *relative* paths
- `/page01.jsp` and `/app/page.html` are examples of *absolute* paths

Back to your question. When using [`RequestDispatcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) by calling [`ServletContext.getRequestDispatcher(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)) you must always forward within your web application and leading slash is necessary (bold mine):

> The pathname must begin with a `/` and is interpreted as relative to the **current context root**.

So when you forward to `/page01.jsp` it is interpreted as: `/your_context/page01.jsp` where `your_context` is the name of your web application.

However when you send redirect to the `/error.jsp` path, servlet container simply sends that address back in 302 response to the browser. Now the browser interprets it as follows: please redirect to `/error.jsp`, an absolute path in the current server. So even if the browser was pointing to `http://example.com/foo/bar/servlet`, this response redirects to `http://example.com/error.jsp`.

It's much different, however, if you simply redirect to `error.jsp` the browser behaves differently. It interprets it as file in current directory. So `http://example.com/foo/bar/servlet` will be redirected to `http://example.com/foo/bar/error.jsp`. And this is what you see.

Answer (score 0):

try the servlet mapping in web.xml , instead of calling file using name, just call using value, defined in web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

please remeber some points while using sendRedirect() and getRequestDispacher() in the same page

1) if you use sendRedirect() and getRequestDispacher("").include() in same page always the output of sendRedirect() that is calling url will be printed on UI.

2) 1) if you use sendRedirect() and getRequestDispacher("").forward(req,res) in same page then you will get Excetion  "Cannot forward after response has been committed".